# JavaEE - Singleton EJB Timer doesn't work

Tags: jakarta-ee, ejb

I want to print the string "qui" every 5 seconds.
I have created an EJB singleton and through annotations I defined a timeout method. I expected that the string "qui" was printed every 5 seconds , but this does not happen. The string "qui" is printed in continuation. My Application server is Glassfish.
Below there is my code:

```
import EJBData.AuctionFrontEndLocal;
import javax.annotation.PostConstruct;
import javax.annotation.Resource;
import javax.ejb.EJB;
import javax.ejb.Singleton;
import javax.ejb.Startup;
import javax.ejb.Timeout;
import javax.ejb.TimerConfig;
import javax.ejb.TimerService;

/**
 *
 * @author melix
 */
@Startup
@Singleton
public class Timer{

    @EJB
    private AuctionFrontEndLocal auctionFrontEnd;

    private Timer timer;

    @Resource TimerService tservice;

    @PostConstruct
    public void initTimer(){
      tservice.createIntervalTimer(0,5000,new TimerConfig());
    }

    @Timeout
    public void timeout() {
      System.out.println("QUI!");
    }

}
```

Comment: Could you use application server logs instead of println?

Comment: Try deleting the tmp and data folders of your AS as an earlier version of your timer may mix things up.
Also you can try deploying your code with a new project. I have seen this problem on JBoss EAP 6.2 and though I don't know the actual cause the same code that didn't work in one deployment works in another.

Comment: Dear @Nunzio Meli , I have a problem: when I use `@Timeout` Icould not load the scheduler at startup even I use `@Startup`. please have a look at: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42242037/parameterize-ejb-scheduler-with-schedule-expression

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your code seems ok... here is my working example:

```
package com.mycompany.mavenproject2;

import java.util.logging.Logger;
import javax.annotation.PostConstruct;
import javax.annotation.Resource;
import javax.ejb.Singleton;
import javax.ejb.Startup;
import javax.ejb.Timeout;
import javax.ejb.TimerConfig;
import javax.ejb.TimerService;

@Startup
@Singleton
public class NewSessionBean {

    @Resource
    private TimerService ts;

    @PostConstruct
    public void init() {
        final TimerConfig tc = new TimerConfig();
        tc.setPersistent(false);
        ts.createIntervalTimer(0, 5000, tc);
    }

    @Timeout
    public void timeout() {
        Logger.getLogger(NewSessionBean.class.getName()).severe("==> timeout called...");
    }

}
```

console output when i run it in glass fish 4.1

```
Information:   mavenproject2 was successfully deployed in 721 milliseconds.
Schwerwiegend:   ==> timeout called...
Schwerwiegend:   ==> timeout called...
Schwerwiegend:   ==> timeout called...
```

Comment: Dear @StefanHeimberg , I have a problem: when I use `@Timeout` Icould not load the scheduler at startup even I use `@Startup`. please have a look at: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42242037/parameterize-ejb-scheduler-with-schedule-expression

Answer (score 3):

try it a bit simpler.

```
import javax.ejb.Schedule;
import javax.ejb.Singleton;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;

@Singleton
public class Timer {
    public Timer () {
        LoggerFactory.getLogger(this.getClass()).info("Starting timer");
    }

    @Schedule (persistent = false, second = "*", minute = "*", hour = "*")
    private void second () {
        LoggerFactory.getLogger(this.getClass()).info("Second");
    }

    @Schedule (persistent = false, second = "*/2", minute = "*", hour = "*", info = "Second Second")
    private void secondSecond () {
        LoggerFactory.getLogger(this.getClass()).info("Second Second");
    }

    @Schedule (persistent = false, second = "*/3", minute = "*", hour = "*")
    private void thirdSecond () {
        LoggerFactory.getLogger(this.getClass()).info("Third Second");
    }
}
```